# Delete specifics data in datagridview and in database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I've already done the Update button. When i want to "delete" data, by that i mean deleting the data in the cell of the datagridview, and i'm clicking on the update button, i have an error => System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : 'String or binary are going to be truncate'.
After some research, i've been told that it was in the case of inserting data and because of the limit length of the data (exemple : nvarchar => 25, it's because we're inserting 30 caracters). But here, i'm deleting..

Thank you for your help.

Code :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection maConnexion = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");
    maConnexion.Open();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if ((row.Cells[19].Value != null) && (bool)row.Cells[19].Value)
        {
            SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();
            command = new SqlCommand("update FailOnly set Machine=@Machine, ProgCode=@ProgCode, BoardName=@BoardName, BoardNumber=@BoardNumber, Tester=@Tester,DateTest=@DateT,TimeTest=@TT,TimeStart=@TS,FComponent=@FC, MMessage=@Message, TotalTestProg=@TTP, ReadValue=@RV, ValueReference=@VR,PTolerance=@PT , FaultCodeByOp=@Fault, RepairingDate=@RD, RepairingTime = @RT, ReportingOperator=@RO WHERE SerialNum=@Serial", maConnexion);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Machine", row.Cells[0].Value != null ? row.Cells[1].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial", row.Cells[1].Value != null ? row.Cells[1].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProgCode", row.Cells[2].Value != null ? row.Cells[1].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BoardName", row.Cells[3].Value != null ? row.Cells[1].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BoardNumber", row.Cells[4].Value != null ? row.Cells[1].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tester", row.Cells[5].Value != null ? row.Cells[1].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateT", row.Cells[6].Value != null ? row.Cells[1].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", row.Cells[7].Value != null ? row.Cells[1].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TS", row.Cells[8].Value != null ? row.Cells[1].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FC", row.Cells[9].Value != null ? row.Cells[1].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message", row.Cells[10].Value != null ? row.Cells[1].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TTP", row.Cells[11].Value != null ? row.Cells[1].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RV", row.Cells[12].Value != null ? row.Cells[1].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VR", row.Cells[13].Value != null ? row.Cells[1].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PT", row.Cells[14].Value != null ? row.Cells[1].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fault", row.Cells[15].Value != null ? row.Cells[15].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RD", row.Cells[16].Value != null ? row.Cells[16].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RT", row.Cells[17].Value != null ? row.Cells[17].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RO", row.Cells[18].Value != null ? row.Cells[18].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    maConnexion.Close();
    this.Hide();
    Repair rep = new Repair();
    rep.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the code it look weird to me that for many of the parameter's you are assigning row.Cells[1].Value. Which results in the following exception 'String or binary are going to be truncate' This might be a miss case but here is your updated code

```
   if ((row.Cells[19].Value != null) && (bool)row.Cells[19].Value)
        {

            SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();
            command = new SqlCommand("update FailOnly set Machine=@Machine, ProgCode=@ProgCode, BoardName=@BoardName, BoardNumber=@BoardNumber, Tester=@Tester,DateTest=@DateT,TimeTest=@TT,TimeStart=@TS,FComponent=@FC, MMessage=@Message, TotalTestProg=@TTP, ReadValue=@RV, ValueReference=@VR,PTolerance=@PT , FaultCodeByOp=@Fault, RepairingDate=@RD, RepairingTime = @RT, ReportingOperator=@RO WHERE SerialNum=@Serial", maConnexion);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Machine", row.Cells[0].Value != null ? row.Cells[0].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial", row.Cells[1].Value != null ? row.Cells[1].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProgCode", row.Cells[2].Value != null ? row.Cells[2].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BoardName", row.Cells[3].Value != null ? row.Cells[3].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BoardNumber", row.Cells[4].Value != null ? row.Cells[4].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tester", row.Cells[5].Value != null ? row.Cells[5].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateT", row.Cells[6].Value != null ? row.Cells[6].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", row.Cells[7].Value != null ? row.Cells[7].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TS", row.Cells[8].Value != null ? row.Cells[8].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FC", row.Cells[9].Value != null ? row.Cells[9].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message", row.Cells[10].Value != null ? row.Cells[10].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TTP", row.Cells[11].Value != null ? row.Cells[11].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RV", row.Cells[12].Value != null ? row.Cells[12].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VR", row.Cells[13].Value != null ? row.Cells[13].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PT", row.Cells[14].Value != null ? row.Cells[14].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fault", row.Cells[15].Value != null ? row.Cells[15].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RD", row.Cells[16].Value != null ? row.Cells[16].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RT", row.Cells[17].Value != null ? row.Cells[17].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RO", row.Cells[18].Value != null ? row.Cells[18].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();


        }
```

Comment: Oh god, i feel so ashamed. I totally forgot to change this cells too. It's working now thank you.

Comment: No need to be ashamed it happens to every mere mortal out there who codes.